# laravel models accessing results from hasManyThrough with 3 tables

Tags: laravel, collections, model, relationship

I have three tables:

PhaseTasks

| phaseId | taskId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |

Tasks

| taskId | taskName | defaultResource |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Do a thing | 1 |
| 2 | Do another thing | 1 |
| 3 | do some other thing | 2 |

resources

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Engineering |
| 2 | Support |
| 2 | Sales |

I am trying to get a result set where i can print

Phase Id: 1, TaskName: Do a thing, ResourceName: Engineering

Phase Id: 1, TaskName: Do another thing, ResourceName: Engineering

Here is my phaseTasks Model:

```
    public function phaseTasks(){

    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        resources::class,
        tasks::class,
        'id',
        'id',
        'taskId',
        'defaultResource'
    );
}
```

and my controller:

```
$phaseData = phaseTasks::with('phaseTasks')->where('phaseId','1')->get();
```

i cant get the task table info,  nor can i figure out how to access the resource data. I DO see the resource data in the print_r($phaseData), i do not see the tasks stuff, im guessing i need to get into pivots for that part.

***EDIT

I was able to figure out how to get the resources.name entity

$phaseData[0]->phaseTasks[0]->name;

now i just need to figure out how to get the taskName entity.

Comment: Have you tried `$phaseData[0]->Tasks[0]-> taskName;` ?

Comment: yea, I am not even seeing the Tasks array() section in the print_r.  I do see the phaseTasks section.

Comment: Kindly check the response of relation, are you getting the task values?

Comment: i do not see anything related to the tasks table in the $phaseData collection

Comment: Try to keep the naming convention Laravel has to offer to make things a lot easier. Why are you using `hasManyThrough`? It’s a `hasMany`/`belongsTo` for both models.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think you got the relationship the other way around: it's not hasmany (through) but belongs to.

So, phasetasks - task_id belongs to a task - default resource belongs to a resource

And your phasetasks looks like a pivot table in itself, but that may be ok.

So if you agree with my assumption and create the relations my way, try something like

```
PhaseTask::with('task.resource')->get();
```